# ClickOnce - Client Requirements

Tags: .net, clickonce

I am currently working with some users that do not have the .NET Framework installed. I have a ClickOnce application I am attempting to deploy. This has lead me to arrive at two questions:

1. What is the minimum version of the .NET Framework required on these users machines? I have heard .NET 2.0 and .NET 3.5.
2. If a user has .NET 2.0 do they need admin privileges to upgrade to .NET 3.5?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As bare minimum, you will need .NET 2.0 on your machine (otherwise the .application file will not be recognized) and I do not think you need admin rights for .NET 3.5.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked in order to make the system recognize an existing Application Reference File.

Answer (score 11):

Contrary to the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373341/clickonce-client-requirements/1373373#1373373), you do not need to have the .NET Framework installed in order to use ClickOnce. You're not supposed to use the .application file directly - doing so bypasses the prerequisite check. ClickOnce marks the appropriate version of the .NET Framework as a prerequisite and installs it as such when you use the setup.exe.

However, the user *does* require privileges to "install" if they will be installing the .NET Framework via ClickOnce. Another interesting point to note is that the user *does not* require "install" privileges to install ClickOnce apps if they already have the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

The framework required would depend on the application you are deploying and which framework it is targeting.  If you are not sure, I believe the setting in VS 2008 is on the project properties, Compile tab, Advanced button.

Not sure about the admin requirements, so I won't guess.